# Embedding PDF into Excel - three questions

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, embed

I have written a macro to allow for embedding a PDF file into an Excel sheet. I want the icon for the file to show up in a certain cell. So far, so good, but I do have some questions.

But first, my code that does the embedding of the file:

```
Range("AN5").Select

ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="AcroExch.Document.DC", Link:=False, _
    DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
    IconIndex:=0, IconLabel:=NameForPDFIcon, _
    IconFileName:="C:\WINDOWS\Installer\{AC76BA86-7AD7-1033-7B44-AC0F074E4100}\PDFFile_8.ico").Activate
```

My questions:

1. I would like the icon to be in the center of Cell AN5, but instead it is justified to the top and left. If I add in Top and Left numbers into the OLEObjects.Add line, it will move the icon into cell A1. I can't figure out how to use Top & Left relative to the cell I have selected.
2. Whenever the file is embedded, the PDF opens in Adobe Reader. Is there a way to have it NOT open?
3. The IconFileName part has the very long string of letters and numbers. (I got this from recording a macro of me inserting a PDF into a sheet.) It looks like a registry address. If I use this file on another computer, will the icon show up there? I assume this long string of characters would be different on another computer? Anyone know how I can make it so this works no matter what computer it's running on? I plan to send this file to several other people when it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32235897/how-to-embed-documents-using-vba

```
Declare Function FindExecutable Lib "shell32.dll" _
     Alias "FindExecutableA" (ByVal lpFile As String, _
                              ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
                              ByVal lpResult As String) As Long


Sub tester()
    AddFile ActiveSheet.Range("H10"), "C:\Users\jblow\Desktop\Training.pdf"
    AddFile ActiveSheet.Range("H20"), "C:\Users\jblow\Desktop\Info.xlsm"
End Sub

Sub AddFile(c As Range, sFile As String)

    Dim exe As String, o

    exe = FindApp(sFile)

    Set o = c.Worksheet.OLEObjects.Add(Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
            IconFileName:=exe, IconIndex:=0, _
            IconLabel:="Testing", Top:=c.Top, Left:=c.Left, _
            Filename:=sFile)

    o.ShapeRange.Width = c.Width '<< fit to cell

End Sub

Function FindApp(sFile As String) As String
   Const MAX_FILENAME_LEN = 260
   Dim i As Integer, s2            As String

   'Check if the file exists
   If Dir(sFile) = "" Or sFile = "" Then
      MsgBox "File not found!", vbCritical
      Exit Function
   End If
   'Create a buffer
   s2 = String(MAX_FILENAME_LEN, 32)
   'Retrieve the name and handle of the executable, associated with this file
   i = FindExecutable(sFile, vbNullString, s2)
   If i > 32 Then
      FindApp = Left$(s2, InStr(s2, Chr$(0)) - 1)
   Else
      MsgBox "No association found !"
   End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you.  With a little bit of adjustment, I was able to make this work.  I do hope to make my workbook work on both Windows & Mac, so any idea how I would make it work on Mac?  I assume the Declare Function at the top would not work on Mac?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea how you'd do the equivalent on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

1. From [OLEObjects.Add Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/oleobjects-add-method-excel), To use the Left argument, *'The initial coordinates of the new object, in points, relative to the upper-left corner of cell A1 on a worksheet, or to the upper-left corner of a chart.'* So if you want the icon in the middle of AN5, you would have to sum the column widths from A:AM and row heights from 1:4 then add about half the column width of column AN. You might try discarding Select and using Range("AN5").OLEObjects.Add ... that should make OLEObjects consider AN5 as a relative A1.
2. Don't Activate the object on insertion.
3. The GUID should be common to anyone who has your version of Adobe installed.

Comment: Thank you. These suggestions definitely helped me!